# What to use instead of Smartmatch?

Tags: regex, perl

I just upgraded to Perl 5.26.1, now I get

```
Smartmatch is experimental at check_tr.pl line 67.
```

where the code in question is

```
my @patterns = (qr/summary:\s+(.+?) in\s+(.+?) - average of\s+(.+?)$/,
        qr/summary:\s+(.+?) in\s+(.+) (.+? .+?)$/);
my $r = "";
opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;
while(my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

    next if ($file =~ m/^\./);
     open(F, '<', "$dir/$file") or die $!;

     if (<F> ~~ @patterns) {
         $r .= <F>;
...
```

**Question**

Ideally with as few changes to the code as possible. What should I do instead of smart matching?

Comment: You can add `use experimental 'smartmatch'` see https://metacpan.org/pod/experimental for more information

Comment: Remarkable timing.  5.26.2 came out about a week ago.  8D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just spell out what you mean. E.g. if you want to check whether the header line matches any regex in `@patterns`:

```
use List::Util 'any';
...
my $line = <F>;
if (any { $line =~ $_ } @patterns) { ... }
```

Though in that case, it might be more sensible to pre-compile a single pattern such as:

```
my ($pattern) = map qr/$_/, join '|', @patterns;
...
if (<F> =~ $pattern) { ... }
```

If your `@patterns` array contains different kinds of data, you might want to choose a different matching operator, e.g. `==` or `eq`. If the `@patterns` are not all the same “type” and you really want the smartmatch behaviour, you can silence the warning and continue to use it:

```
use experimental 'smartmatch';
```

However, this might then break without further warnings in the future.

Comment: I have update OP with the regex that `@patterns` contain. The reason to pre-compile, is that because of performance? I would prefer your `any` example as it would be easier to understand in later on.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting If you find `any` or `grep` easy to understand, use that. Readability is important. Yes, pre-compiling the regex might be a bit more efficient since the alternatives can be checked within the regex engine, without having to execute any Perl code. Note that your second pattern matches anything that the first pattern would match. They only differ in case you access the captures.

Answer (score 6):

The reason Smartmatch is experimental is that it is so hard to figure out what it will do without referencing the [Docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator).  Even so, how do we interperet the above code?

Is this a case of:

```
ARRAY1    ARRAY2     recurse on paired elements of ARRAY1 and ARRAY2[2]
            like: (ARRAY1[0] ~~ ARRAY2[0])
                    && (ARRAY1[1] ~~ ARRAY2[1]) && ...
```

Where we presume `<F>` is interpreted in list context and emptied in a single call?

Or is this a case of:

```
 Any       ARRAY      smartmatch each ARRAY element[3]
            like: grep { Any ~~ $_ } ARRAY
```

I'm going to guess the 2nd.  In which case the snippet above from the docs gives you an excellent (and clearer) coding alternative.  Presuming `@patterns` contains regexes, you can also replace the `~~` with `=~`.

---

If you don't like the `grep` alternative from the docs, I'd recommend looking into either `List::Util` or `List::MoreUtils`.  Both contain an `any` call which acts as a short-circuiting `grep`.  Alternatively, if you are trying to implement the `ARRAY1 ARRAY2` option, the later library contains a `pairwise` call that may serve.

Comment: I have updated the OP and yes, `@patterns` are regex's =) `grep` would be perfect, as it is easy to understand in a year from now.

Answer (score 2):

Have to agree with the other answers that Perl's *smartmatch* is better avoided.

There is a list of alternatives (with examples) on Perl-Monks site:
[PerlMonks - Smartmatch alternatives](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1067462)

Answer (score 0):

For situations where you have several shapes of data to compare with, and you don't want a long list of if / elsif in your code to go over all possible situations, then the  [match::simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/match::simple) module by TOBYINK is a pretty good replacement for the old smartmatch.